# Group multiple columns by a single column in pandas and concatenate the rows of each column being grouped

Tags: python, pandas, list, pandas-groupby

I have the following list of columns and Dataframe in pandas respectively

```
import pandas as pd
df_1=pd.DataFrame()
files_list=["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"]
df_1["ID"]=["S", "S", "T", "L", "L", "L"]
df_1["Col1"]=[["A"], ["A1"], ["B"], ["B2"], ["C2"], ["D1"]]
df_1["Col2"]=[["R"], ["R1"], ["S"], ["R2"], ["Q2"], ["T1"]]
df_1["Col3"]=[["y"], ["ii1"], [], ["m2"], ["i2"], ["p1"]]
```

The dataframe looks like this.

```
  ID  Col1  Col2   Col3
0  S   [A]   [R]    [y]
1  S  [A1]  [R1]  [ii1]
2  T   [B]   [S]     []
3  L  [B2]  [R2]   [m2]
4  L  [C2]  [Q2]   [i2]
5  L  [D1]  [T1]   [p1]
```

I need to group the columns Col1, Col2 and Col3 to result in the following dataframe

```
     ID     Col1          Col2                Col3
   0  S   [A , A1]      [R, R1]              [y, ii1]
   2  T   [B]           [S]                  []
   3  L   [B2, C2, D1]  [R2, Q2, T1]         [m2, i2, p1]
```

I have tried the following code

```
 files_list=["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"]
 df_1 = df_1.groupby('ID').agg( {files_list})
```

I have also tried this

```
 df_1=df_1.groupby(['ID'])(files_list).apply(','.join).reset_index()
```

Is there a way to accomplish this . I would like to know where I am making a mistake here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nested list comprehension in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with filtered columns names in `list`:

```
files_list=["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"]
f = lambda x: [z for y in x for z in y]
df_1 = df_1.groupby('ID', sort=False, as_index=False)[files_list].agg(f)
```

If performance is not important or small DataFrame is possible use `sum` for join lists:

```
files_list=["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"]
df_1 = df_1.groupby('ID', sort=False, as_index=False)[files_list].agg(sum)
print (df_1)
  ID          Col1          Col2          Col3
0  S       [A, A1]       [R, R1]      [y, ii1]
1  T           [B]           [S]            []
2  L  [B2, C2, D1]  [R2, Q2, T1]  [m2, i2, p1]
```

Comment: Thank you. Will [files_list] trigger an error as it is a list within a list?

Comment: @Raghavanvmvs - No, in last pandas version is it also required, else warning `FutureWarning: Indexing with multiple keys (implicitly converted to a tuple of keys) will be deprecated, use a list instead.` if use `df_1.groupby('ID', sort=False, as_index=False)["Col1", "Col2", "Col3"].agg(f)`

Comment: Thank you. Timely and will help